# WMI .NET Invalid query

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wql

I keep getting an "Invalid Query" exception when trying to execute the following query:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskQuota WHERE QuotaVolume.DeviceID = 'C:'");
ManagementObjectCollection quotaCollection = searcher.Get();
```

However this works: "SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskQuota".

According to MSDN:

> For most uses of class descriptors in a WHERE clause, WMI flags the
>   query as invalid and returns an error. However, use the dot (.)
>   operator for properties of type object in WMI. For example, the
>   following query is valid if Prop is a valid property of MyClass and is
>   type object:
>
> SELECT * FROM MyClass WHERE Prop.embedprop = 5

Does it mean this only works if Prop declared as OBJECT?

Here are the exception details:

```
System.Management.ManagementException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Invalid query 
  Source=System.Management
  StackTrace:
       в System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
       в System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
       в UserQuota.Program.getQuota() в c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UserQuota\UserQuota\Program.cs:строка 40
       в UserQuota.Program.Main(String[] args) в c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\UserQuota\UserQuota\Program.cs:строка 33
       в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Looks right.  You need to catch the exception and paste the contents into an [edit].  Call ToString on the object, or use the exception dialog (click the "paste contents to clipboard" link at the bottom).

Comment: I've added the exception but seems it doesn't have much details...

Comment: I edited my answer with sample code which will hopefully help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. According to the [Win32_DiskQuota class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394136(v=vs.85).aspx#properties), the QuotaVolume property is a reference to a Win32_LogicalDisk WMI class. The quotation from MSDN you supplied gave the reason why the query is invalid according to the WQL specs.

Instead, you can use something like this:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskQuota WHERE QuotaVolume = \"Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=\\\"C:\\\"\"");
ManagementObjectCollection quotaCollection = searcher.Get();
```

(Notice all the escaping...)